# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor DateTime.Parse don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to do a cast with dates but it's throws me an exception
.

The code is:

This Works ->

```
var FechaInicio = Model != null ? DateTime.Parse(Model.FechaInicio).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Parse("").Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This Doesn't Work ->

```
var FechaFin = Model != null ? DateTime.Parse(Model.FechaFin).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Parse("").Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The model is Ok and values are dates in string format

The error is:

Server Error in '/' Application.
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error:

```
Line 13:    var Ubicacion = Model != null ? Model.Ubicacion : null;
Line 14:    var FechaInicio = Model != null ? DateTime.Parse(Model.FechaInicio).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Parse("").Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
Line 15:    var FechaFin = Model != null ? DateTime.Parse(Model.FechaFin).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Parse("").Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: What do you expect `DateTime.Parse("")` to do?

Comment: Anything, but trying other way:  var FechaFin = Model != null ? DateTime.Parse(Model.FechaFin).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); also doesn't work.

Comment: I just need to get the date existing in Model.FechaFin into the variable FechaFin in dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 1):

The error is straight-forward. The string being passed to `Parse` could not be interpreted as a valid `DateTime`. By default, the format of the current culture is employed, when using `Parse`. Not sure what that is exactly in your case, but it would likely be the same as you would see by outputting `DateTime.Now.ToString()`.

The reason `DateTime.Today.ToString()` failed, is because the output will only have a date component. The default format utilized by `Parse` will require date and time components.

If you need to parse a string into a `DateTime` that doesn't match the format of the current culture, then you need to use `ParseExact` instead of `Parse` and pass a format string that shows how the string-based datetime is formatted.